# Check if a string only contains letters - Email Validation

Tags: java, android, arrays, authentication

I'm new to Android developing.
In my login authentication activity, I want validation for input fields. 
I want the characters after "." to be letters only.

ehsan@gmail.**com**

If user typed a String like this: ehsan@gmail.23 return false and make a Toast.
my code is:

```
String email = "ehsan@gmail.com";
String[] ar = email.split(".");

    if ( !ar[ar.length -1].matches("[a-z]") ){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your email is invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return false; }
```

When I run this code, the app force closes.
What is wrong?

Comment: You probably should use [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) to match/validate whole email address at the same time.

Comment: I've provided an answer based on what you asked, but frankly, there are a million regex examples available online to validate email. Don't reinvent the wheel, unless you're paid by the hour.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the `Patterns` class to validate the email address:

```
public static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

Comment: Is this an Android specific class? There's no `Patterns` class in the JDK.

Comment: You have to import `android.util.Patterns`

Comment: So, the answer to my question is "yes, `Patterns` is an Android specific class"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not complitely sure, but I suppose that problem is character @, its not in a-z interval. Hence, try

```
!ar[ar.length -1].matches("[a-z@]")
```

Also, keep in mind that e-mail could contain other special characters as '_' for example

Answer (score 1):

`email.matches(".+\\.[a-zA-Z]+")` seems to do the job. It's not the most sophisticated regex in the world, but it works.

`valid@gmail.com` matches.
`invalid@gmail.a1b` doesn't match.